# Why is my error value increasing for this simple implementation of a neural network?

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, neural-network

My error value increases when I subtract the gradient  x learning rate (of 0.5) from each parameter.

Shouldn't the error value be decreasing when I do so?

Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

params = {}

params["W1"] = np.random.rand(5,20)
params["W2"] = np.random.rand(20,10)
params["b1"] = np.zeros(20)
params["b2"] = np.zeros(10)

# creating training data values
S = np.array([[1,0,0,1,0],
             [1,0,0,0,1],
             [1,0,0,1,1],
             [0,0,1,1,0],
             [0,1,1,0,0],
             [0,1,1,0,0],
             [0,0,0,0,1],
             [0,0,1,0,0],
             [1,0,0,0,1],
             [1,1,1,0,1]])

# creating actual classification values for the training data
simple_array = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
t_train = np.zeros((simple_array.size, simple_array.max()+1), dtype=int)
t_train[np.arange(simple_array.size),simple_array] = 1 


def predict(S):
    #find a1
    a1 = np.dot(S, params["W1"]) + params["b1"]
    
    # calculate z1 = relu(a1)
    z1 = []
    for row in a1:
        row0 = []
        for element in row:
            row0.append(max(0.0, element))
        z1.append(row)
    z1 = np.array(z1)
    
    # calculate a2 = b2 + z1*W2
    a2 = np.dot(z1,params["W2"]) + params["b2"]
    
    # calculate z2 = softmax(a2)
    
    z2 = []
    for i in range(len(a2)):
        row = a2[i] - np.max(a2[i])
        summation = np.sum(np.exp(row))
        row = np.exp(row)/summation
        z2.append(row)
    z2 = np.array(z2)
    return z2

def loss(S):
    predictions = predict(S) #10*10 array
    error = -np.sum(t_train*np.log(predictions + 1e-7))
    return error

loss_list = []
loss_list.append(loss(S))

#finding numerical derivative and updating parameters

h = 0.0000001
for m in range(100):
    for i in range(int(params["W1"].shape[0])):
        for j in range(int(params["W1"].shape[1])):
            params["W1"][i][j] += h
            bef = loss(S)
            params["W1"][i][j] -= h*2
            aft = loss(S)
            params["W1"][i][j] += h
            deriv = (aft - bef)/(2*h) 
            params["W1"][i][j] -= 0.5*deriv
    
    
    for i in range(int(params["W2"].shape[0])):
        for j in range(int(params["W2"].shape[1])):
            params["W2"][i][j] += h
            bef = loss(S)
            params["W2"][i][j] -= h*2
            aft = loss(S)
            params["W2"][i][j] += h
            deriv = (aft - bef)/(2*h) 
            params["W2"][i][j] -= 0.5*deriv
    
    for i in range(int(params["b1"].shape[0])):
            params["b1"][i] += h
            bef = loss(S)
            params["b1"][i] -= h*2
            aft = loss(S)
            params["b1"][i] += h
            deriv = (aft - bef)/(2*h) 
            params["b1"][i] -= 0.5*deriv
            
    for i in range(int(params["b2"].shape[0])):
            params["b2"][i] += h
            bef = loss(S)
            params["b2"][i] -= h*2
            aft = loss(S)
            params["b2"][i] += h
            deriv = (aft - bef)/(2*h) 
            params["b2"][i] -= 0.5*deriv

    loss_list.append(loss(S))

plt.plot(np.array(loss_list))
```

This is the graph I get:
[Plot obtained by subtracting gradient x learning rate from parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2keb.png)

Also, when I add the gradient x learning rate to parameters, I get a decreasing loss function. I am not sure why, as I would expect the opposite to happen.

[Plot obtained by adding gradient x learning rate to parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Puqtk.png)

Comment: In gradient descent, the error value should decrease as you update the parameters by subtracting a fraction (called the learning rate) of the gradient from its current value. If the error is increasing instead, this could be due to the learning rate being too large, getting stuck in a local minimum or saddle point, or other issues such as overfitting or insufficient training data. Try using a smaller learning rate, a different optimization algorithm, regularization, or more training examples to resolve these issues.

Comment: I don't know why, but when I add the fraction of the gradient to the parameters to update them, after a 100 runs, I get an almost perfect classification of the training data. Does this mean that be adding the fraction to the parameters, I'm somehow correctly training my model?

Comment: I have a feeling it's a problem with my code such that I somehow messed up + and - signs...but I'm unable to find it

Comment: In gradient descent the parameters are updated in the opposite direction of the gradient, which is the direction of the steepest desceent. This means that subtracting the gradient multiplied by the learning rate from the parameters should move them in the opposite direction and lead to a decrease in the loss.

Comment: Doing some testing I will let you know what I find.

Comment: So I made some edits and I'm getting the same results. 
I tried lowering the learning rate and that seemed to help a little bit but I still got a high loss value. I recommend that you try using more training data.

Comment: Hmm thanks for your input. However, I increased training size to 80 samples and still the same problem appears to be happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason why your loss is increasing is that you calculate the *opposite* of the [symmetric difference quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_derivative).

In your code, you have:

```py
params["W1"][i][j] += h
bef = loss(S)
params["W1"][i][j] -= h*2
aft = loss(S)
params["W1"][i][j] += h
deriv = (aft - bef)/(2*h) 
params["W1"][i][j] -= 0.5*deriv
```

If you switch the second and fourth lines (and do the same for other hyperparameters), the loss starts to decrease.

Some other problems include not actually calculating the ReLU activation function (you're appending `row` instead of `row0` to the new array) and I'm not sure if changing the value of the parameter while calculating its gradient is correct. Besides that, the code looks ready for some hyperparameter tuning :)

Here's my final version:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

params = {}

params["W1"] = np.random.rand(5, 20)
params["W2"] = np.random.rand(20, 10)
params["b1"] = np.zeros(20)
params["b2"] = np.zeros(10)

# creating training data values
S = np.array(
    [
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    ]
)

# creating actual classification values for the training data
simple_array = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
t_train = np.zeros((simple_array.size, simple_array.max() + 1), dtype=int)
t_train[np.arange(simple_array.size), simple_array] = 1


def predict(S):
    # find a1
    a1 = np.dot(S, params["W1"]) + params["b1"]

    # calculate z1 = relu(a1)
    z1 = []
    for row in a1:
        row0 = []
        for element in row:
            row0.append(max(0.0, element))
        z1.append(row0)
    z1 = np.array(z1)
    assert np.all(z1 >= 0.0)

    # calculate a2 = b2 + z1*W2
    a2 = np.dot(z1, params["W2"]) + params["b2"]

    # calculate z2 = softmax(a2)

    z2 = []
    for i in range(len(a2)):
        row = a2[i] - np.max(a2[i])
        summation = np.sum(np.exp(row))
        row = np.exp(row) / summation
        z2.append(row)
    z2 = np.array(z2)
    assert np.allclose(np.sum(z2, axis=1), 1.0)
    return z2


def loss(S):
    predictions = predict(S)  # 10*10 array
    error = -np.sum(t_train * np.log(predictions + 1e-7))
    return error


loss_list = []
loss_list.append(loss(S))

# finding numerical derivative and updating parameters

h = 0.0000001
alpha = 0.5
for m in range(100):
    W1 = params["W1"].copy()
    for i in range(int(params["W1"].shape[0])):
        for j in range(int(params["W1"].shape[1])):
            params["W1"][i][j] += h
            aft = loss(S)
            params["W1"][i][j] -= h * 2
            bef = loss(S)
            params["W1"][i][j] += h
            deriv = (aft - bef) / (2 * h)
            W1[i][j] = params["W1"][i][j] - alpha * deriv
    params["W1"] = W1

    W2 = params["W2"].copy()
    for i in range(int(params["W2"].shape[0])):
        for j in range(int(params["W2"].shape[1])):
            params["W2"][i][j] += h
            aft = loss(S)
            params["W2"][i][j] -= h * 2
            bef = loss(S)
            params["W2"][i][j] += h
            deriv = (aft - bef) / (2 * h)
            W2[i][j] = params["W2"][i][j] - alpha * deriv
    params["W2"] = W2

    b1 = params["b1"].copy()
    for i in range(int(params["b1"].shape[0])):
        params["b1"][i] += h
        aft = loss(S)
        params["b1"][i] -= h * 2
        bef = loss(S)
        params["b1"][i] += h
        deriv = (aft - bef) / (2 * h)
        b1[i] = params["b1"][i] - alpha * deriv
    params["b1"] = b1

    b2 = params["b2"].copy()
    for i in range(int(params["b2"].shape[0])):
        params["b2"][i] += h
        aft = loss(S)
        params["b2"][i] -= h * 2
        bef = loss(S)
        params["b2"][i] += h
        deriv = (aft - bef) / (2 * h)
        b2[i] = params["b2"][i] - alpha * deriv
    params["b2"] = b2

    loss_epoch = loss(S)
    print(m, loss_epoch)
    loss_list.append(loss_epoch)

plt.plot(np.array(loss_list))
```